# Is my algorithm correct? (value in the range or not)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, range

I need to determine whether my special string is in the specific range or not?

Example:

```
// range
[
  "01-01-001-001",
  "01-01-001-140"
]
// string
"01-01-001-001"
```

We need to detect whether string is in specified range?
A string represents as set of "levels" separated by dash("-"):

```
 4    3    2     1
01 - 01 - 001 - 001
```

4,3,2,1 are weights. 4 is highest and 1 is lowest.

Below is my `isInRange` function that checks that:

```js
 function isCodeInRange (code, range) {
  var start = range[0].split('-'),
      end = range[1].split('-'),
      parts = code.split('-')
  ;

  if (parts[0] !== start[0]) {
    return false;
  }


  for (var i = 1, len = parts.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (!(Number(parts[i]) >= Number(start[i]) && Number(parts[i]) <= Number(end[i]))) {
       if ((Number(parts[i - 1]) >= Number(end[i - 1]))) {
         return false;
       }
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(isCodeInRange(
    '01-01-140-01',
    ['01-01-138-01', '01-02-140-01']
))
```

So as you can see, the result of that check is true. Some tests:

```
console.log(isCodeInRange(
    '01-02-140-01',
    ['01-01-138-01', '01-02-140-01']
)) // true

console.log(isCodeInRange(
    '01-01-101-01',
    ['01-02-138-01', '01-03-140-01']
)) // false

console.log(isCodeInRange(
    '01-01-001-01',
    ['01-01-001-01', '01-01-140-01']
)) // true
```

Is my algorithm correct? Do they cover all possible corner cases?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point but why can't you just take `code` and `range` and `parseInt(code.replace(/\-/g, ''))` and compare them as numbers? You could add some validation with a regex if necessary to make sure the code/range was formatted properly?

Comment: `parts[0] !== start[0]` why you have this check ? i.e start -> `01-01-01-01` , end -> `10-10-10-10`, code -> `02-02-02-02` shouldn't it pass ?

Comment: why is the first of three false?

Comment: _"Is my algorithm correct? Do they cover all possible corner cases?"_ - How about testing your code? Test valid ranges, test invalid ranges, test invalid input, ...

Comment: what's wrong with `range[0] <= string && string <= range[1]`?

Comment: Sorry guys for mistakes in my example, I've fixed `true/false` in example.  I've used `parts[0] !== start[0]` due to specific in my application code (checking with comparing also would work).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Checking and testing your code is *your* responsibility.  Until you have a demonstrable error, you do not have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.
Specifically check out the Code Review site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string and map numbers and check against the ranges.

```js
function isCodeInRange(values, ranges) {
    ranges = ranges.map(s => s.split('-').map(Number));
    return values
        .split('-')
        .map(Number)
        .every((v, i) => ranges[0][i] <= v && v <= ranges[1][i]);
}

console.log(isCodeInRange('01-02-140-01', ['01-01-138-01', '01-02-140-01'])); // true not false
console.log(isCodeInRange('01-01-101-01', ['01-02-138-01', '01-03-140-01'])); // false
console.log(isCodeInRange('01-01-001-01', ['01-01-001-01', '01-01-140-01'])); // true
```

A version without `every` and ES5.

```js
function isCodeInRange(values, ranges) {
    var every = true;
    ranges = ranges.map(function (s) { return s.split('-').map(Number); });
    values
        .split('-')
        .map(Number)
        .forEach(function (v, i) {
            every = every && ranges[0][i] <= v && v <= ranges[1][i];
        });

    return every;
}

console.log(isCodeInRange('01-02-140-01', ['01-01-138-01', '01-02-140-01'])); // true not false
console.log(isCodeInRange('01-01-101-01', ['01-02-138-01', '01-03-140-01'])); // false
console.log(isCodeInRange('01-01-001-01', ['01-01-001-01', '01-01-140-01'])); // true
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I'm just curious, why I use plural for `values` and `ranges` ? `value` should be singular.

Comment: you have four parts ... so plural.

Comment: Hi Nina! Would it possible to translate this code in ES5? I know that it possible but would be great to see how to keep it such concise (especially w/o `every`) ?

Comment: `every` is part of ES5.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the browsers where this method is not implemented :)

Comment: and what would you want now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200674/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-erik).

Comment: `every` is not a function. I run this code in NodeJS of `v0.12`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for this case `console.log(isCodeInRange('01-02-140-01', ['01-01-001-01', '01-03-139-01'])); // false` should be `true`

Comment: but why . . . ?

Comment: This is my requirement. `02` level i between `01` and `03`

Comment: what about the next value? it is larger than the upper bound.

Comment: Like in my approach?